# How can i output this html with xsl( I want to exit an element)

Tags: xslt

I have this xsl bellow :

```
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
  <div id="vtab">
    <ul>
      <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body"/>
    </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
  <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('TitleKey', @Title))]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:variable name="thisClassification" select="@Title" />
    <div>
      <xsl:for-each select="../Row[@Title = $thisClassification]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Model"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like have this output:

```
               <div id="vtab">
                <ul>
                    <li>HTC</li>
                    <li>Nokia</li>

                </ul>
                    <div>HTC Sensation 345-HTC Ev</div>
                    <div>Nokia</div>
                </div>
```

But now this is what i'm getting

```
<div id="vtab">
<ul>
<li>HTC</li>
<div>HTC Sensation 345HTC Evo</div>
<li>Nokia</li>
<div>Nokia</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can i exit the UL element and start the  DIV element.
Thanks alot

Comment: How can you have such code? Don't mind but it doesn't look so readable! This is acceptable for a beginner for a reason, but you are a 200+ score user!?

Comment: Aravind My bad guys.Its what i got from Sharepoint Designer and as you know it doesn't format well :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not optimal, but consider making two loops something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div id="vtab">
            <xsl:call-template name="LOOP_1"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="LOOP_2"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="LOOP_1">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('TitleKey', @Title))]">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                </li>
                <xsl:variable name="thisClassification" select="@Title"/>
                <div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../Row[@Title = $thisClassification]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Model"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="LOOP_2">
        <div>
            <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('TitleKey', @Title))]">
                <xsl:variable name="thisClassification" select="@Title"/>
                <div>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../Row[@Title = $thisClassification]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Model"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure of your requirements, but it may be more efficient to review the desired output, and output nested lists and format it using CSS rather than creating separate loops

Comment: Please note this is not the complete XSLT as the keys were not shown in the original example

Comment: Thanks Chris.That helped me got what i wanted.
Didn't add:
 <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('TitleKey', @Title))]"> 
to my child before